# distribution of the score of a game

Tags: probability

Consider a shooting game with the following rules

- if the player hits the bull’s-eye (event B) the round is stopped and the player scores +1;
- if the player doesn’t hit the target (event M) the round is stopped and the player scores -1;
- if the player hits the target but not the bull’s eye (event A) the player loses 0.01 and shoots again.

The shots are independent. Let $X_i$ be the total score at round $i$ (that is the sum of the scores at each round). The distribution of $X_i$ at a given round $n$ should be

- $P(X_n = 1 -(n-1)0.01)) = P(B)P(A)^{(n-1)}$;
- $P(X_n = -1 -(n-1)0.01)) = P(M)P(A)^{(n-1)}$;
- $P(X_n = -n0.01) = P(A)^n$.

However, these don't sum up to $1$ but to $P(A)^{(n-1)}$. What am I doing wrong?

Naturally, $P(B) + P(M) + P(A) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't sum up to $1$ because there is a chance the game has already ended before $n$. Guess what that probability is? Yes, $1-P(A)^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: Yes. So obvious after reading the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.